# Sketching the graph of a function

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

How would I sketch the graph of the following function.

Sketch the graph of a function satisfying the following conditions

$f(1)=2$

$f(-1)=f(3)=-1$

$f'(1)=0$

$f'(x)>0$ for all $x<1$

$f'(x)<0$ for all $x>1$

$f''(-1)=f''(3)=0$

$f''(x)>0$ for all $x<-1$ and for all $x>3$

$f''(x)<0$ for all $-1<x<3$

$\displaystyle \lim _{x\to \infty}$ $f(x)=-3$.

Comment: It should be in the shape of a bell.

Comment: Note:  the task is to sketch **a** graph.  (It's not unique.)  Which of the criteria are you having trouble with?

Comment: The derivative are kind of confusing me and the conditions a bit..

Comment: Think about what it means for a function's first and second derivatives to be zero at certain points. You may find [this](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/ShapeofGraphPtII.aspx) and [this](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/ShapeofGraphPtI.aspx) article helpful.

Comment: @nikbougalis with those helpful website I think I understand how to graph to betterthanks

Comment: Great. Good luck :)

Comment: for my final answer I got concave up increase from (-negative infinity,x=-1) concave down increase from x=-1 to  x=1 concave down decrease from x=1 to x=3 concave up decrease x=3 to infinity